# Problems with implementation of chunked upload using ng-file-upload

Tags: ng-file-upload

I am looking for solution how to implement chunked upload with **[ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)**

I read in documentation that I can set chunk size by

```
resumeChunkSize: 10000 or '10KB' or '10MB'
```

But also I have to implement the following promise:

```
resumeSize: function() {return promise;}
```

But there is no any example, how can I implement it.

I googled it quite long but was not able to found any solution.

I will be very grateful for any help!

Comment: The demo page has an example of that. Basically you can set a `resumeSizeUrl` which is a url on the server that returns how much of the file is already uploaded so the client would send the file from that point where we are left. `resumeSize` is for the case that you have a customized way of getting the current uploaded size rather than a simple http get so you can implement a promise that makes a call to the server and resolves to the uploaded size.

Comment: @danial, thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: @OlegSchepotkin